# How to keep values in register form after error?

Tags: php

My code works perfect with correct data. But when is invalid value in field, it shows an error message with link on page register.php and when I click on this error, it redirects to register form, but there is empty form and all values must be inserted again. I want that valid values are displayed after error and invalid not.

Code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        
        <?php include 'connect.php'; ?>
        <?php include 'functions.php'; ?>  
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>TechnoLab-Registracija</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css' />
        <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
        
             <div id="left">
                <?php include "kategorije.php";?>
            </div>
            
            <div id="right">
                <?php include "loggedin.php";?> 
            </div>
      
       <form method="post" id='registerform'> 
           <br/>
        <?php
if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) )
{
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']));
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $confirm_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['confirm_email']);
    $ime = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ucfirst($_POST['ime']));
    $prezime = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ucfirst($_POST['prezime']));
    $oib = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['oib']);
    $ulica = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['ulica']);
    $mjesto = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['mjesto']);
    
   
    
    $checkusername = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM korisnici WHERE Username = '".$username."' OR Oib = '".$oib."'");
   
     if(mysqli_num_rows($checkusername) == 1)
     {
       
        echo "&nbsp<p><a class='one' href=\"register.php\">Unesite drugo korisničko ime!</p>";
        exit();
     }
    
    $checkusernamelenght = checkusernamelenght($username);
       if(!$checkusernamelenght){
           echo '&nbsp<p><a class="one" href="register.php">Korisničko ime minimalno 4 znaka i ne smije sadržavati razmake između slova!</a></p>';
           exit();
       }
       
    if (preg_match("/^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $_POST['password']) === 0){
        echo '&nbsp<p><a class="one" href="register.php">Lozinka mora imati barem 6 znakova i sadržavati mala i velika slova te broj!</a></p>';
        exit();
        }
       
    $checkemail = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM korisnici WHERE Email = '".$email."'");
   
    if(mysqli_num_rows($checkemail) == 1)
     {
        echo "&nbsp<p><a class='one' href=\"register.php\">Unesite drugu email adresu!</p>";
        exit();
     }
    if ($confirm_email!=$email){
             echo "&nbsp<p><a class='one' href=\"register.php\">Vaše email adrese se ne podudaraju!</a></p>" ;
             exit();
         }
         
         
    $validateEmail = validateEmail($email);
      if(!$validateEmail){
          echo "&nbsp<p><a class='one' href=\"register.php\">Unesite ispravan format emaila!</a></p>";
          exit();
      }
      
     
    $checkOib = checkOib($oib);
    if(!$checkOib){
        echo "&nbsp<p><a class='one' href=\"register.php\">Unesite ispravan OIB !</p>";
        exit();
    }
      
    else{
        $registerquery = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO korisnici VALUES('', '$username', '$password', '$email', '$confirm_email', '$ime', '$prezime', '$oib', '$ulica', '$mjesto', 'user')");
        if($registerquery)
        {
            header('location: index');
           
        }
    }       
    }
   
 
else
{
    ?>
<br/>
            <div id="reg">
       
        <label for="username">Korisničko ime:</label><input type="text" name="username" required /><br />
        <label for="password">Lozinka:</label><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="20" required /><br />
        <label for="email">Email:</label><input type="text" name="email" required /><br />
        <label for="confirm_email">Potvrdi email:</label><input type="text" name="confirm_email" required /><br />
        <label for="ime">Ime:</label><input type="text" name="ime" required /><br />
        <label for="prezime">Prezime:</label><input type="text" name="prezime" required /><br />
        <label for="oib">OIB:</label><input type="text" name="oib"  required /><br />
        <label for="ulica">Ulica i kućni broj:</label><input type="text" name="ulica" required /><br />
        <label for="mjesto">Mjesto i poštanski broj:</label><input type="text" name="mjesto" required /><br />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Registracija" />
        
            </div>
       </form>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    
   
        </div>
        
        
        <?php include "footer.php";?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible do that only with php or must be javascript or something else?

I've searched on forum and tried with this and similar code but it doesn't work.

```html
<input type="text" name="login" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['login'])){ echo $_POST['login'];}?>">
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: just create an array with valid values and put its value in input fields, eg: 
`<label for="username">Korisničko ime:</label><input type="text" value="<?=$username?>" name="username" required /><br />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$_POST['<value>']` doesn't work because of the redirect, it "drops" the `$_POST` data.

One way to achieve the desired functionality is to use `$_SESSION` when the form has been submitted you can store the values in the `$_SESSION`, or you might prefer to only store them if there's a error.)

You can store/save the values in `$_SESSION` like so:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
```

And then simply check for the `$_SESSION['<value>']` instead of the `$_POST['<value>']`.

```
<input type="text" name="login" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['login'])){ echo $_SESSION['login'];}?>">
```

You'd have to remember to start the session at the top of each page you want to use sessions on.

```
session_start();
```

One thing to be aware of is that you should unset the session values after you are done with them, so you avoid old data being reused.

There are plenty of ways you can use `$_SESSION` to achieve what you want so it's all about finding the way that suits you best.

You can [read more about sessions here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Answer (score 0):

best way is to create session array for complete data and if it is not empty show it in your fields. other method is to pass that post array back to your view when redirecting after invalid values.
hope you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the `register.php` script to fill the fields, simply send the needed info to this script:

```
$param  = "?user=".urlencode($_POST['user']);
$param .= "&amp;email=".urlencode($_POST['user']);
//...concat all needed param here
echo "&nbsp<p><a class='one' href=\"register.php".$param."\">Unesite drugo korisničko ime!</p>";
```

Then in your `register.php` script, just read the $_GET['...'] values to populate your form. don't forget to `urldecode()` them.

**Note:** For obvious security reasons, DO NOT pass the password in the GET parameters (nor store it in a $_SESSION variable).